# Error: Expected one of #, input, filter, output at line 34, column 1 (byte 1) after {:level=>:error} in logstash

Tags: linux, logstash, elastic-stack

Hi i am trying to setup ELK server for log management . My  logstash service is running fine .I am receiving logs from other machine but logstash pipeline is not able to send data to elastic search
When i look at the logstash .log file it shows this error
I am not able to identify the error in my configuration file

```
:message=>"Error: Expected one of #, input, filter, output at line 34, column 1 (byte 855) after ", :level=>:error}
```

my logstash/conf.d

```
input {
beats {
port => 5044
ssl => true
ssl_certificate => "/etc/pki/tls/certs/logstash-forwarder.crt"
ssl_key => "/etc/pki/tls/private/logstash-forwarder.key"
}
}
filter {
if [type] == "syslog" {
grok {
  match => { "message" => "%{SYSLOGTIMESTAMP:syslog_timestamp} %{SYSLOGHOST:syslog_hostname} %{DATA:syslog_program}(?:\[%{POSINT:syslog_pid}\])?: %{GREEDYDATA:syslog_message}" }
  add_field => [ "received_at", "%{@timestamp}" ]
  add_field => [ "received_from", "%{host}" ]
}
    syslog_pri { }
    date {
  match => [ "syslog_timestamp", "MMM  d HH:mm:ss", "MMM dd HH:mm:ss" ]
}
}
}
output {
elasticsearch {
hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
sniffing => true
manage_template => false
index => "%{[@metadata][beat]}-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
document_type => "%{[@metadata][type]}"
}
}
{
"mappings": {
"_default_": {
  "_all": {
    "enabled": true,
    "norms": {
      "enabled": false
    }
  },
  "dynamic_templates": [
    {
      "template1": {
        "mapping": {
          "doc_values": true,
          "ignore_above": 1024,
          "index": "not_analyzed",
          "type": "{dynamic_type}"
        },
  "match": "*"
      }
    }
  ],
  "properties": {
    "@timestamp": {
      "type": "date"
    },
    "message": {
      "type": "string",
      "index": "analyzed"
    },
    "offset": {
      "type": "long",
      "doc_values": "true"
    },
    "geoip"  : {
      "type" : "object",
      "dynamic": true,
      "properties" : {
        "location" : { "type" : "geo_point" }
      }
    }
  }
}
},
"settings": {
"index.refresh_interval": "5s"
 },
"template": "filebeat-*"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error happens when there are files in /etc/logstash/conf.d directory which logstash can not parse. Remove them and see if this helps. In my case, I had the same error when reports.xml file was presented in conf.d directory.

Comment: yeah man the conf.d should only have input output and filter file